# NoSuchKey Error While Downloading File From Bucket

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I tried to download a file from the bucket but I got an error like this

```
(Signed URL link) NOT FOUND: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message></Error>
```

Basically the implementation is something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
        url2 = providers.get(i).getRemoteGetUrl(a);
        url2.setChunk(chunks.get(providers.get(i)));
        list2.add(i, url2);
        System.out.println("URL Get from Download "+ url2);
}
```

with a is the constant name of the file to be stored in the bucket. I'm still able to download this file but it gave me this warning in the console and it took longer compared with downloading the file from different storage provider of AWS that happened without any error.

Is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks

Comment: "The specified key does not exist" means that GCS can't find an object of that name. Check the URL you're fetching and make sure that the bucket and object in it match a real object.

Comment: I already checked and the bucket name and the object name (in this case a constant string variable called a" but still same warning error. I'm still able to download this file but there is only warning message of it.

Comment: Are you perhaps using App Engine's local development server?

Answer (score -1):

`NoSuchKey`The specified key does not exist.resources/html5gs/undefinedD93K9V6EHSSM3MA5OlyGAPwwx1AAhkhbdYQU/g0qZbg1Z2Dsgbxvkx484NxPpWv6wSqWm4/Hnbs20cmmDteqfHnESzE=

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean?